# SQL referencing destination column name in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

*Long time listener, first time caller. So any tips on how to better word my question would be appreciated.*

In Amazon Redshift, I am using a CASE statement in my SELECT clause and I need to reference the destination column. However, the destination and source columns have the same name. For example:

```
SELECT 
   CASE when c.state = 'null' then NULL else UPPER(c.state) END as state,
   FROM external_data.stu_temp c
   WHERE state IN NOT NULL;
```

Doesn't work as intended because the `WHERE state` bit is actually referencing `c.state`

This variation does work:

```
SELECT 
   CASE when c.state = 'null' then NULL else UPPER(c.state) END as state2,
   FROM external_data.stu_temp c
   WHERE state2 IN NOT NULL;
```

But because I am doing a bunch of UNIONs, I need my destination column name to be `state` not `state2`

Comment: Can you share a pseudo code that illustrates this problem as part of the unions you're doing ? We can see if there is a less clumsy way of getting at that

Answer (score 0):

Either repeat the expression or use a subquery:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT CASE when c.state = 'null' then NULL else UPPER(c.state) END as state
      FROM external_data.stu_temp c
     ) c
WHERE state IN NOT NULL;
```

This is how *SQL* is defined.  You cannot re-use a column alias in the `WHERE` clause (or `FROM` or depending on the database, in other clauses as well).

There is a good reason for this -- and your code illustrates the issue.  How should the compiler determine which `state` the code refers to?  It could make a guess or apply a rule.  However, the designers of SQL thought it better to just generate an error so the code is unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a cheat code to keep multiple columns straight without having to use nested queries (much like there is when using JOINs if you don't have conflicting names you can just use `state` but when you do you can use `a.state` `c.state` etc.). Your answer sparked an idea since I do already have a bunch of UNIONs in a nested query. I could use that to convert the names without having to nest another query.